# For decreasing $a_n > 0$, for what increasing $f:{\mathbb N} \to {\mathbb N}$ does $\sum_n a_n$ converge iff $\sum_k f(k) a_{f(k)}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

A classical result says that for a positive decreasing sequence $a_n$, the series $\sum_n a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_k 2^k a_{2^k}$ converges. From the proof, it seems that we could replace $2^k$ with $f(k) = \lfloor c^k \rfloor$ for any constant $c > 1$ and get that $\sum_n a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_k f(k) a_{f(k)}$ converges. Is this true? And is this the only aysmptotic form of $f(k)$ for which this result holds? I.e., is there any other non-linear increasing $f(k)$ which is not $\Theta(c^k)$ for some $c > 1$, such that arbitrary $\sum_n a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_k f(k) a_{f(k)}$ converges (where $a_n$ is arbitrary positive decreasing)? If not, can someone give a proof?

Comment: It holds for $f(k) = \lfloor c^k\rfloor$ if $c > 1$. What one needs (for the proof I have in mind) is that $\dfrac{f(k+1)-f(k)}{f(k)}$ and $\dfrac{f(k) - f(k-1)}{f(k)}$ are - for large $k$ - both bounded above, and bounded away from $0$. For sequences of exponential growth, that is the case. I'm not sure, but I think it holds only for sequences of exponential growth.

Comment: Guess what? the wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#Generalizations) on the condensation test contains a generalization.

Comment: Thanks! The forward difference coefficients $f(k+1) - f(k)$ don't have the form $\Theta(f(k))$ I asked for unless $f(k)$ grows exponentially, but this is indeed a generalization. If you post as an answer, I'll accept it.